# How can I generate SQL to build a database from my model in Visual Studio when not using MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

When using Entity Framework with SQL Server, I can build the model in VS and it'll generate the SQL that builds the database automatically for me, including building lookup tables for handling many <-> many relationships.

How can I do this for other relational databases, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL? Everything I've found for non-MSSQL databases seems to assume code-first instead of model first development for EF.

Comment: Rewritten question to not be a 'recommend' question.